# Help unbind all materials from selected object

Tags: python, materials, scripting, objects

i hope someone can help me, is it possible in python to give object e.g. "Sphere" its own materials? (single-user option)

I hope someone can help me.

(Blender 2.92.0)

[image: pic]

Comment: What you want is “localize materials with Python” or “change what’s in a material slot with Python.” So… which one?

Comment: “change what’s in a material slot with Python.”

Comment: I just try to unbind the material from the other. so that the object has its own materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it affects all selected objects.

```
import bpy
for ob in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for ms in ob.material_slots:
        if ms.material and ms.material.users > 1:
            ms.material = ms.material.copy()
```

Note that it may not do what you expect if an object has two slots with the same material.

Comment: is it possible that they get a "new" material instead of a "copy" of it?

Comment: because the node system no longer functions according to the main material. :l

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.